# Very basic LibGDX game - where is my model, view and controller?

Tags: android, design-patterns, model-view-controller, libgdx

I have to give a presentation on my Android game on Friday and just wanted to know exactly where MVC is used in my game. Right now it uses 4 classes: **MyGdxGame**, ***GameObject*** (abstract) **Player** (extends GameObject, implements inputProcessor), **Platform** (extends GameObject)

Player jumps when screen is tapped or dashes when screen is dragged.

So right now I know that Player is my **Model**.

I'm guessing MyGdxGame is my **View** (2 methods - create() and render())

Where is my controller? Also have I implemented the Observer/observable pattern by using InputProcessor in Player? Here is an example of how I used it:

```
@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    if (isDragged == false && allowDash == true) {
        isDragged = true;
        dash();

    }
    isDragged = false;
    setxSpeed(4.6f);
    return false;
}
```

Any insight is highly appreciated (and thanks in advance)

Comment: well if the Player implements the inputProcessor, I'd guess that's your controller. And there isn't enough code here to reasonably assess whether the architecture is properly separated, and in that case, I think the right place to ask that would be on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt reply. The inputProcessor is a listener though, is there a reason why it's the controller and not observer? Also do I need to have my model, view and controller all in a separate class for it to count as an MVC implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also have I implemented the Observer/observable pattern by using InputProcessor in Player?

Generally yes. Listeners usually implement the Observable design pattern. Remember though that design patterns are not set in stone and are more like "guidelines" in a way, but I am assuming you need to show evidence of design patterns in your code for school or whatever you are doing on Friday. What I am trying to say is don't implement design patterns for the sake of implementing a design pattern.

In an android project, the activity.java files are usually seen as controllers for the MVC design pattern, the xml files are the view, and other java files are the model.

But in your case, with libgdx, you are correct in assuming that Player is the model and MyGdxGame is the view. The controller can be seen as the inputProcessor as EpicPandaForce suggested, or basically any other section of your code where the user is specifically using that code to manipulate the model.